# Is it possible to modify classloader behaviour without starting a new VM?

Tags: java, classloader, abstract-syntax-tree

Testing the results of AST transformations and source generation with Annotation processors, and I have a classloader that can load the compiled (modified) classes into and instantiate them after I run a unit test with google's compile testing so I can also unit test the behavior of the generation/class modification when they are instantiated.  Here is my classloader:

```
public ClassLoader createClassLoader(com.google.testing.compile.Compilation compilation)
            throws InstantiationException,
            IllegalAccessException,
            ClassNotFoundException,
            IOException, NoSuchFieldException {

    return new ClassLoader() {

        final List<JavaFileObject> files = getFiles(compilation);

        @Override
        protected Class<?> findClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
            System.out.println("Loading compiled class: " + name);

            JavaFileObject mc = this.getFileFromName(name, files);

            if (mc != null) {

                try {

                    byte[] bytes = new byte[5000];

                    int len = mc.openInputStream().read(bytes);
                    files.remove(mc);

                    return defineClass(name, bytes, 0, len);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            return super.findClass(name);
        }

        private JavaFileObject getFileFromName(String name,
                                               List<JavaFileObject> input) {
            return input.stream().filter(object -> {
                final URI normalize = object.toUri().normalize();
                String curr = normalize.toString();
                curr = curr.substring(("mem:///CLASS_OUTPUT/").length(),
                        curr.length() - ".class".length());
                curr = curr.replace("/", ".");
                return Objects.equals(curr, name);
            }).findAny().orElse(null);
        }
    };
```

This works and I can instantiate objects from class files that I compiled in unit tests:

```
ClassLoader loader = (new CompilerUtil().createClassLoader(compilation));
Class clazz = loader.loadClass(fullName);
Object instance = clazz.newInstance();
```

I would like to be able to modify the existing one so that I can run the compilation tasks and have it recognize the classes that are dynamically loaded when running compilation tests with "-printsource" args etc..

It's for unit tests so Reflection/Instrumentation is fine, wondering if there's an easy way to either load the classes with the current classloader or possibly replace it?

Comment: To reload updated classes, you generally throw away the classloader and create a new one. If the code loaded by the classloader doesn't have memory leaks, the Garbage Collector will free up the memory of the old classloader and the classes loaded by it.

Comment: @Andreas my compiler plugin is compiled first, and then compiles raw source that technically doesn't even exist in the initial compilation - my processor is built into a jar on the test classpath & the test classes are in a resources folder off of the classpath.  I'm trying to simulate compilation of other source code and also trying to test the results in one go so I guess it isn't updated classes because they didn't exist before the test compilation

Comment: @Andreas it's just that when running the tests with like "printsource" it can't locate the compiled classes and throws "class not found" error